# Creating multiple variables from a single question

Tags: python

I have a program that collects school subject types (math, english, chemistry ...) and then it asks what teachers teach those subjects. This is used to help create student timetables.

I have a question

`input ("What subjects are there..")`

Then the program creates a list with all those subjects
`e.g subjects = [math, english, ...]`.

Then the program asks what teachers are connected to what subjects.
So pretty much it asks for a subject and asks for teachers involved.
How can I in my program assign for example Math with Mr Bob and Miss Stacey and English with Miss Lane and Mr Ace.

The only thing I have tried is doing the list and assigning each subject with a position in the list but I don't know how to assign teachers with each subject are there could be 6 that teach English and only 2 that teach math.

Comment: Please format the question. Also show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't been clear on where you're at with this challenge, so I'm going to try to point you in the right direction by suggesting you familiarize yourself with the various collection types Python supports: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Give some thought to which data structures you will need and it should be fairly easy to figure out how the program needs to be structured as well.

An Array, List or Set could be used to capture the list of subjects (simply append to it until you're done creating the list). Sets have the advantage of deduplicating your list for you but otherwise, there's no real practical difference for this application.

Once that's done, you probably want to look at a Dictionary (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to store a map of subjects to teachers.

Comment: Thank you, I'm fairly new to python so I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: I am briefly familiar with dictionaries and lists and the ability to add and remove inputs but I guess my key question is how can I create a dictionary/list when both my variables are unknown. (not sure if variables is the right word) So I ask what subjects . Exmaple is Subjects = [Math, English...]    Then my dictionary would be SubjectTeachers = {Math : Mr. Bob and Miss Tina, English : Mr James and Miss Kylie} When asking what teachers are involved how do I insert them into the dictionary to their specific subject. Thanks,

Comment: You can add to a dictionary using SubjectTeachers['English'] = 'Mr James' - dictionaries are not immutable.

Comment: Cheers mate for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using dictionaries. Using your example -

```
dict1 ={'Math':['Mr Bob','Miss Stacey'],'English':['Miss Lane','Mr Ace']} 
print(dict1['Math'])    --> To access all the teachers who teach math
print(dict1['Math'][1])
```

If you need to add a 'Mr Stallone' to Math, you need to retrieve the value against 'Math' and then edit/append it.

```
dict1['Math'].append('Mr Stallone')
```

dict1['Math'] = 'Mr Stallone' Is incorrect and will just replace the entire value against 'Math'.

The above is great if you intend to list the teachers for a specific subject. If you plan to list out the subjects against a particular teacher your dictionary will be different.

```
dict2 ={'Mr Bob':['Math','Chemistry'],'Miss Lane':['English','subject1'].....}
print(dict2['Mr Bob'])    --> To access all the subjects that Mr Bob teaches
```

Initially you can create an empty dictionary -->  dict1={}
As you add subjects you need to add an empty list as the value --> dict1['Math']=[]
When you're added teachers to that subject --> dict1['Math'].append['Mr champ']

Comment: Thanks mate, do dictionaries have the ability to add input from user. Such as "What subjects does Mr Bob teach" And from that input you can add it into the dictionary. So my dictionary would be empty and then I ask what subjects are there, (they get entered into the dictionary) and then what subjects does ***** teach and that gets input in.

Comment: If this has answered your question please mark it so on the answer so it this can be closed.